# My package on PyPi cannot find relevant files

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

I'm trying to upload my first package on PyPi. Everything seems to be good except my function cannot access the relevant files within the package. Error is as follows.

```
File "/Users/my_username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deepcut/deepcut.py", line 134, in tokenize
with open('weight/object.pk', 'rb') as handle:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'weight/object.pk'
```

I've checked that pip actually installed my files with the package. Here is what is in my installed directory /Users/my_username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deepcut

```
__init__.py
deepcut.py
__pycache__
  ...
weight
  best_cnn.h5
  object.pk
```

The folder I used to create package consist of

```
LICENCE.txt
MANIFEST
MANIFEST.in
README.rst
setup.dfg
setup.py
deepcut
  __init__.py
  deepcut.py
  weight
    best_cnn.h5
    object.pk
```

The content of setup file is as follows.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import setuptools

setup(
  name = 'deepcut',
  packages = ['deepcut'], 
  package_dir={'deepcut': 'deepcut'},
  package_data={'deepcut': ['weight/*']},
  include_package_data=True,
  version = '0.5.0.13',
  install_requires=['keras', 'pandas', 'scipy', 'numpy'],
  license='MIT',
  description = 'A Thai word tokenization library using Deep Neural Network',
  author = 'Rakpong Kittinaradorn',
  author_email = 'r.kittinaradorn@gmail.com',
  url = 'https://github.com/rkcosmos/deepcut',
  download_url = 'https://github.com/rkcosmos/deepcut/package/0.5.zip', 
  keywords = ['thai word segmentation deep learning neural network development'],
  classifiers = ['Development Status :: 3 - Alpha'],
)
```

and MANIFEST.in

```
# Include the license file
include LICENSE.txt
include README.rst

# Include the data files
recursive-include deepcut *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using an absolute path instead.

```
# this will be the path that the file is stored in
# which for you should be /Users/my_username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deepcut/
path_to_module = os.path.dirname(__file__) 

# now just join it with the file in the weight folder
weight_path = os.path.join(path_to_module, "weight", "object.pk")
with open(weight_path, 'rb') as handle:
    pass
```

Comment: That would work only for me but how about other people downloading my package?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem — `path_to_module` is calculated dynamically based on where the package is installed.